# Numpy matrix row stacking

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 4 arrays (all the same length) which I am trying to stack together to create a new array, with each of the 4 arrays being a row.

My first thought was this:

```
B = -np.array([[x1[i]],[x2[j]],[y1[i]],[y2[j]]])
```

However the shape of that is `(4,1,20)`.

To get the 2D output I expected I resorted to this:

```
B = -np.vstack((np.vstack((np.vstack(([x1[i]],[x2[j]])),[y1[i]])),[y2[j]]))
```

Where the shape is `(4,20)`.

Is there a better way to do this? And why would the first method not work?

**Edit**

For clarity, the shapes of `x1[i], x2[j], y1[i], y2[j]` are all `(20,)`.

Comment: Are `x1`, `x2, `y1`, `y2` the arrays or `x1[i]`, `x2[j]`, `y1[i]`, `y2[j]` the arrays? i.e. why are you indexing into them?

Comment: x1[i] etc are the arrays, indexed they are all the same size.

Comment: Then why doesn't `np.vstack((x1[i], x2[j], y1[i], y2[j]))` work?

Comment: it does, but is there a better way to do it? it seems like a really unclear way of doing it.

Comment: Not really, I think - I'll add a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the extra brackets:

```
B = -np.array([[x1[i]],[x2[j]],[y1[i]],[y2[j]]]) # (4,1,20)
B = -np.array([x1[i],x2[j],y1[i],y2[j]])         # (4,20)
```

`[[x1[i]]` is `(1,20)` in shape.

```
In [26]: np.array([np.ones((20,)),np.zeros((20,))]).shape
Out[26]: (2, 20)
```

`vstack` works, but `np.array` does just as well.  It's `concatenate` that needs the extra brackets

```
In [27]: np.vstack([np.ones((20,)),np.zeros((20,))]).shape
Out[27]: (2, 20)

In [28]: np.concatenate([np.ones((20,)),np.zeros((20,))]).shape
Out[28]: (40,)

In [29]: np.concatenate([[np.ones((20,))],[np.zeros((20,))]]).shape
```

`vstack` doesn't need the extra dimensions because it first passes the arrays through `[atleast_2d(_m) for _m in tup]`

Answer (score 2):

`np.vstack` takes a sequence of equal-length arrays to stack, one on top of the other, as long as they have compatible shapes. So in your case, a tuple of the one-dimensional arrays would do:

```
np.vstack((x1[i], x2[j], y1[i], y2[j]))
```

would do what you want. If this statement is part of a loop building many such 4x20 arrays, however, that may be a different matter.